# In zsh, how to expand a file of glob patterns?

Tags: zsh

Given a file `globs.txt` containing lines of glob patterns, what's a nice way to expand them all into one line?

I.e., given

```
$ cat globs.txt
a/b*
c/d*
```

and

```
$ ls prefix/*
a:
brunch lunch

c:
dance lance

x:
banana
```

I want to get `prefix/a/brunch prefix/c/dance`.

My current approach is:

```
(for line in $(cat globs.txt); do g=prefix/$line; print $~g; done) | tr "\n" " "
```

Comment: I don't get it. What is it that you don't like about your current solution?

Comment: I just thought there has to be a simpler way to do this. E.g. to do the globbing in one step instead of line by line, but `g=$(cat globs.txt | sed 's!^!'prefix/'!' | tr "\n" " "); print $~g` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is a simpler way ;-)

```
echo prefix/${^~$(<globs.txt)}
```

Comment: This is great! I suppose we still need `echo ${~$(<globs.txt | sed 's!^!prefix/!')}` to apply the prefix to all lines, but I like this much better.

Comment: Nope.  Why don't you try it instead of guessing how it behaves?

Comment: I don't guess. This was a nice way of saying it doesn't work exactly like this. Depending on where glob.txt lives, I either get `no matches found: c/d*` (outside of prefix/) or `no matches found: prefix/a/b*` (inside prefix/).

Comment: Ah, sorry - I see.  You have your shell options set differently to me then.  I was assuming that `rc_expand_param` is set, and maybe `nullglob` too.  I've added an `^` character to the answer which temporarily enables `rc_expand_param` behaviour.  `nullglob` behaviour can also be enabled by suffixing with `(N)` but you probably don't need that here.  The command *must* be run from outside of `prefix/`, which means that `globs.txt` has to be too (or if it isn't, change it to `echo prefix/${^~$(<prefix/globs.txt)}`.